# Deploy Asp.net core web app to azure vm using releae pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have simple asp.net core web application. I am trying to deploy it using azure devop release pipeline.

I have followed these steps from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops).

1. Created deployment group
2. Added windows server 2016 datacenter.
3. In release pipeline **IIS Website Deployment** template, and created release.
4. my release is completed with 2 warnings.

[image]

I tried to login in remote the run the application local, but it throw me error.
[image]

Comment: How is it going with this issue? Is below solution working for you?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT: Yes. It worked. I need to install package version as per my project. Sorry I forgot to marked it as answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this error when i tried to deploy a web app locally.

In browser the error showed the configuration file is invalid, 
and in IIS Manager Configuration Editor the error showed the data is invalid.

I downloaded this specific [ASP.NET Hosting Core package](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting), and the page was rendered finally.

You can try downloading and installing above specific package on you VM.